# Physical location of row in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

How to find the physical location of a row in PostgreSQL?
Are the rows stored in disk blocks in the order they are inserted in the table?

I read about types of file organizations in SQL:

- Sequential File Organization
- Heap File Organization
- Hash File Organization
- B+ Tree File Organization
- Clustered File Organization

How to know which data type my database is using?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the language SQL does not make any assumptions about the physical implementation or ordering of a table, so I have no idea where this list comes from. A PostgreSQL table is a heap, a collection of rows with a "random" order.

Storage is organized in 8kB blocks, and the physical address of a row can be accessed through the system column `ctid`. This value is of the form `(42,7)`, where the first number is the number of the 8kB block in the file (starting at 0), and the second number is the item pointer number in the block.

Note that the physical address of a row in the table is highly volatile; it is changed with every `UPDATE`.